# Хостинг для сервера на Java.

Tags: java, сервер

Я написал сервер на java. Посоветуйте пожалуйста хостинг на который можно его поставить, желательно с инструкцией. Нужен не сильно дорого и надёжный. Обмен данных маленький.

Comment: любой VPS хостинг

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понятие "хостинг" обычно применяют к сайтам на интерпретируемых языках, когда все окружение настроено, а вам требуется только закинуть файлы.

Вам нужен VPS/VDS(можете тут порыться - http://hosting101.ru/pricing-plans-vps). После регистрации и оплаты вам будет предоставлен к нему доступ по ssh (в случае *nix) или через Remote Desktop (в случае с Windows). Далее вы,обладая полным доступом к системе, настраиваете и запускаете сервер как на своей локальной машине.